# Apache poi get table from text box

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I'm using apache poi for iteration table in docx file. All works fine but if table in **text box**, my code don't see table - **table.size() = 0**

[image]

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileName));

    List<XWPFTable> table = doc.getTables(); 

    for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : table) { 
        List<XWPFTableRow> row = xwpfTable.getRows();
        for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : row) { 
            List<XWPFTableCell> cell = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells();
            for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : cell) {
                if(xwpfTableCell != null){
                 List<XWPFTable> itable = xwpfTableCell.getTables(); 
                    if(itable.size()!=0){ 
                        for (XWPFTable xwpfiTable : itable) { 
                            List<XWPFTableRow> irow = xwpfiTable.getRows(); 
                            for (XWPFTableRow xwpfiTableRow : irow) { 
                                List<XWPFTableCell> icell = xwpfiTableRow.getTableCells(); 
                                for (XWPFTableCell xwpfiTableCell : icell) { 
                                    if(xwpfiTableCell!=null){   
                                    } 
                                } 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Wow. Who the heck is misusing word processing that way? Tables contained in table cells are weird enough. But a table contained in a shape? I don't believe you can get this table without very special parsing the `*.docx/word/document.xml`.

Comment: Yes, this case is very strange but I should parse this table. You can download docx https://ufile.io/6xmqd

Comment: What exactly is needed? Only reading the table's content? This is possible relatively easy. Or manipulating the table within the rectangle shape? This also possible but much more complicated.

Comment: I want only to read text from table which in text box. Above code works fine for tables in docx without text box

Answer (score 1):

Following code is low level parsing a `*.docx` document and getting all tables in document body of it.

The approach is using a  [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.4.0/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlCursor.java) and searching for all `w:tbl` elements in `document.xml`. If found add them to a `List<CTTbl>`.

Because a text box rectangle shape provides fall-back content in the `document.xml`, we need to skip the `mc:Fallback` elements. Else we would have the tables within the text boxes twice.

At last we go through the `List<CTTbl>` and get the contents of all the tables.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTbl;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTRow;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTc;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTText;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlAnyTypeImpl;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordReadAllTables {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("22.docx"));

  CTBody ctbody = document.getDocument().getBody();

  XmlCursor xmlcursor = ctbody.newCursor();

  QName qnameTbl = new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", "tbl", "w");
  QName qnameFallback = new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006", "Fallback", "mc");

  List<CTTbl> allCTTbls = new ArrayList<CTTbl>();

  while (xmlcursor.hasNextToken()) {
   XmlCursor.TokenType tokentype = xmlcursor.toNextToken();
   if (tokentype.isStart()) {
    if (qnameTbl.equals(xmlcursor.getName())) {
     if (xmlcursor.getObject() instanceof CTTbl) {
      allCTTbls.add((CTTbl)xmlcursor.getObject());
     } else if (xmlcursor.getObject() instanceof XmlAnyTypeImpl) {
      allCTTbls.add(CTTbl.Factory.parse(xmlcursor.getObject().newInputStream()));
     }
    } else if (qnameFallback.equals(xmlcursor.getName())) {
     xmlcursor.toEndToken();
    }
   } 
  }

  for (CTTbl cTTbl : allCTTbls) {
   StringBuffer tableHTML = new StringBuffer();
   tableHTML.append("<table>\n");
   for (CTRow cTRow : cTTbl.getTrList()) {
    tableHTML.append(" <tr>\n");
    for (CTTc cTTc : cTRow.getTcList()) {
     tableHTML.append("  <td>");
     for (CTP cTP : cTTc.getPList()) {
      for (CTR cTR : cTP.getRList()) {
       for (CTText cTText : cTR.getTList()) {
        tableHTML.append(cTText.getStringValue());
       }
      }
     }
     tableHTML.append("</td>");
    }
    tableHTML.append("\n </tr>\n");
   }
   tableHTML.append("</table>");

   System.out.println(tableHTML);

  }

  document.close();

 }
}
```

This code needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in [faq-N10025](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Comment: Thanks Axel, you do my day =) This link will be useful for solving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025

Comment: @nickolson: You are welcome. And thank you for the hint that full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` is needed.

Comment: I believe above code is always suitable for getting tables from *.docx and not depends on how tables "hidden" in document. Am I true?

Comment: @nickolson: Yes, but it gets all tables into the `List` independent of where they are located. For example it gets tables, which are located in cells of other tables, as tables within the `List` too. And, like all my code provided here, it is a short, self contained, correct (compilable), example to show the principles but **not**  code ready to use in  productive environments.

Comment: @HelpingHand: Why asking me?

Comment: @AxelRichter No hard feelings just being curious why :)