# How to read a table in MS-Word, which exists inside a cover page, using JAVA

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to read information from MS-Word files, where tables were inserted into the cover page.
An example using GUI in MS-Word:
1. Select **Insert** command from menu, then choose **Cover Page**
2. Click somewhere inside the cover page and then insert a table using **Insert -> Table**

If I open the document (.docx) using 7zip, I can see the  element, which contains the information I need.
However, it seems I cannot get this information using Apache POI.
The following code returns 0 (zero) tables:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;

public class TestPOI {

    private static final String TEMP_DIR = "D:" + File.separator + "temp" + File.separator;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String sAbsFileName = TEMP_DIR + "EP-17258-1.docx";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sAbsFileName);
    XWPFDocument documentX = new XWPFDocument(fis);
    List<XWPFTable> lTables = documentX.getTables();
    int iTableQty = lTables.size();
    System.out.println("file " + sAbsFileName + " has " + iTableQty + " tables");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have already looked into the `/word/document.xml` then you should have seen that the whole cover page is contained in a `Word` `Content Control`. `Apache poi` only has [Experimental class to offer rudimentary read-only processing of of StructuredDocumentTags/ContentControl](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFSDT.html) which does not providing full reading of such `Content Control`s. So what you wants will only be possible using very low level objects and methods and having good knowledge about the `XML` used in  `/word/document.xml`.

Comment: @Axel Richter Thank you Axel for your prompt answer and insight. I tried this as well but it seems the same result. We will also try the low-level parsing of the document.xml part or just avoid the use of cover pages in company's templates.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054823/apache-poi-get-table-from-text-box/46059749#46059749 I have provided a code which reads all tables in the document.xml. This should also reading tables in `sdtContent` elements.